# How do I fill a PDF with content from an HTML document via JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

I have the following problem:

I need to write the content of an HTML form into a PDF file when the submit-button is pressed, using JSP.
Now let's say my HTML looks like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="PDFTest.jsp" method="POST" role="form" name="TestForm">

            Name <input name="inp_name" />
            First name <input name="inp_firstname" />
            Street <input name="inp_street" />
            Zip-code <input name="inp_zip" />

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The PDF file has also declared fields with the identifiers "inp_name, inp_firstname, inp_street, inp_zip" (I created a form in LibreOffice, added Textfields, named them with the identifiers and exported the form to PDF).

Is it possible to take the input elements by their Name-Tags and copy the content of these elements into the fields of the PDF file? And if it is, how do I do it?
I heard, that something like this could be done with iText, but I never used it before.

Additionally, is it possible to create a copy of the original PDF file in the JSP so that the copy will be filled with the content and the original only serves as a template?

Thanks in advance for your answers/criticism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Flying Saucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) can render HTML to PDF with iText. [Here](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/06/26/generating-pdfs-with-flying-saucer-and-itext.html#generating-a-simple-pdf)'s an example showing how that's done.
You will have to replace the strings in the HTML document prior to conversion.